# Git log include commits that has been excluded?

Tags: git

For example `git log --graph commit_a..commit_b` means to include commits reachable from commit_b and exclude commits reachable from commit_a.

However is there a way to force include commit_a in the above condition? (i.e. to list commits reachable from commit_b but not (commits reachable from commit_a except commit_a itself))

`commit_a^..commit_b` seems to be an easy solution but it doesn't work in some cases: (1) if commit_a is a root commit, an error occurs since commit_a^ doesn't exist; (2) if commit_a is a merge commit, those reachable from commit_a^2 (or maybe ^3, ...) are included, which is not desired.

Furthermore, is there a way to log multiple sequences of commits with graph? Such as: (commits reachable from commit_b but not commits reachable from commit_a) plus (commits reachable from commit_d but not commits reachable from commit_c)

A simple `git log --graph commit_a..commit_b commit_c..commit_d` doesn't work in some cases, e.g. commit_b is an ancestor of commit_c and thus commit_a..commit_b is totally excluded.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you are looking for on your first question:

```
git log --boundary commit_a..commit_b
```